# MVC 4: Force ScriptBundle to return non-optimized links of Javascriptfiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, minify, bundling-and-minification, scriptbundle

We are trying to get the **ScriptBundle** in MVC 4 to return the expanded list of javascript when debug = false in the web.config. By default the ScriptBundle will optimize the javascript into one call when debug=false.

Currently when you set debug=false in the web.config, a **ScriptBundle** will combine and **minify** the javascript files like this:

```
 <script src="/AAA/Scripts/a?dfkjghakjsdfhglkjasdhfkljasdf"></script>
```

We need the **Scriptbundle**, when **debug=false**, to output the javascript expanded, like this:

```
<script src="/AAA/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/AAA/Scripts/jquery.tipTip.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to turn off the **Scriptbundle** optimization?

Why? When we do a https redirect on the site, the **ScriptBundle** optimized script link doesn't work (we get 503 Forbidden on the link)

Comment: You might want to also consider this library. I'm biased of course but it sounds like what you want. https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting this in your BundleConfig.cs file where you are setting up the bundles:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification for more details.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for single files?

Comment: Aside from bundling one file at a time, not that I am aware of.  Might be a good question to submit all on its own and be clear that you are NOT looking for this solution.